# Laravel slow image respond

Tags: laravel, image, performance, nginx, httpresponse

In one of my pages, i display multiple images. I get the images through a route, which is connected to a controller method. Like so:

**In view:**

```
(inside foreach)
<img width="100" src="viewBook/get/...." >
```

**In controller method:**

```
$img = Image::make('images/test.jpg');
        return $img->response('jpg');
```

But this is such an slow approach. When i display let's say 13 images, it almost takes 10 seconds. And when i inspect through Chrome DevTools, most of the time is consumed as "Idle". And of course they get loaded one by one.

How can i make it faster ? Maybe parallel responding, or increasing ngingx bandwidth ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you sending the images through Laravel instead of just serving them directly off the filesystem?

Comment: @ceejayoz Because security is imperative and on point. I don't want user to know anything about the directory infrastructure.

Comment: You'd be better off giving each image an unguessable URL, using something like `str_random` to generate a long random filename. Your users knowing there's an `images` folder isn't a security risk. Sending every image on your site through Laravel is going to be a performance hit.

Comment: @ceejayoz informative, i will look into that. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the Intervention Image package. However, there is no need to put all images through this package. If you do, the package will process the image and this takes a lot of time.

If you just want to return the image, you can do it with a [built-in file response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#file-responses).

```
return response()->file('images/test.jpg');
```

This will load the file directly from the file system and will be much faster.

Comment: I got an error like: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::headers(), i think i miss a package or include right ?

Comment: It seems to be a function I copied from older code of mine that is no longer needed. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, it does load pretty fast. But the problem is i need to use "Intervention Image package", because i use some methods or api's from it. Is there any other workaround to speed it up ?

Comment: @Skywarth The code you shared doesn't show any use of Intervention Image's functionality. If there's code you haven't shared that does stuff like resizing/cropping/etc., take a peek at http://image.intervention.io/use/cache so it doesn't have to run these (computationally expensive) functions for every pageview.

Comment: @ceejayoz You're right. I'll try my chance with the caching, makes sense to use it that way. Will notify after the changes.

Comment: @ceejayoz implemented the caching you mentioned, but unfortunately didn't really change so much. I'll probably use another approach to the problem, instead of cropping on fly.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult thing to improve response time. It depends on various reasons such as server, internet speed, location, size of your images etc.

For such instances, services like imagix(https://www.imgix.com/) can be used, and it worked well for us. It's way cheaper than tuning other parameters to improve response time.